# Ruby rake prints argument but doesn't like it's value on methodcalll

Tags: ruby, syntax-error, task, bundle, rake

I have task:

```
desc "Create a team"
task :create_dev_team, [:team_name] do |t, args|
  puts "Creating \"#{args.team_name}\" team under Sub Org ID: 1"
  ESP::Team.create(name: #{args.team_name}, sub_organization_id: 1)
end
```

The ESP SDK Documentation to create an team is :

*team = ESP::Team.create(name: "Team Name", sub_organization_id: 6)*

when I call that line directly from irb it works fine,

**BUT** when I call :

```
rake create_dev_team[Team Name] --trace
```

I get:

```
rake aborted!

SyntaxError: /Users/me/dev/my-repo/Rakefile:348: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using syntax as if you were interpolating a string:

```
#{args.team_name}
```

But without quoting the string - there is no assumed string here. That means Ruby will treat it as a comment starting at the `#`. Which in turn means that there is no closing `)` in the code. When the parser find the `end`, it is unexpected, since it still thinks the context is inside the method call, so it cannot finish the outer block.

You should either use:

```
ESP::Team.create(name: args.team_name, sub_organization_id: 1)
```

Or:

```
ESP::Team.create(name: "#{args.team_name}", sub_organization_id: 1)
```

The former is what you should use if your method always returns a `String`. Here, `args.team_name` could return `nil`. But you should really check for that earlier and fail the task if so, as an empty team name may cause you problems elsewhere in your code.

Comment: How can I make sure that the args.team_name parameter will be always surrounded by double quotes in ruby?

Comment: @Becks: What you actually want to do is ensure it is a `String`, which is slightly different, the quotes are only important for declaring `String` values directly in the code (a *string literal*). The second option I show does what you want in this case, but doesn't fully address what happens if someone just calls `rake create_dev_team` without a parameter, when the value will be `nil` - turning that into a `String` just gets you `""`, which is probably not a very good name (I don't know for certain, depends on whether you are happy with blank names in your database)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Ideally I would like rake to accept gracefully ONLY something like rake create_dev_team[Team Name] and have team name become "Team Name" for when the sdk call happens: ESP::Team.create(name: "Team Name", sub_organization_id: 1). How do I achieve this?

Comment: Calling rake create_dev_team[Team Name] gives me this error: Don't know how to build task 'create_dev_team[Team'

Comment: @Becks: Those are two different issues to your original question. I suggest do a little research on each issue and if you are still stuck after exploring how it works and trying ideas for 20-30 minutes on each one, then ask another question here.

Comment: ha, I just did. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51090947/cannot-call-ruby-rake-with-parameter-containing-space